# How to search in Excel 2007 (not csv) through C# code?

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I have column A B C D

how to search in Excel (not csv) if "test" in column A - and if found

I want to receive A B C D column's

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working client-side (i.e. your code run on user machine), you can to use Excel API, like describe here: [How to: Search for Text in Worksheet Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx)

Server-side (like in an ASP.NET application) it's a bit harder, as usually you can't install Microsoft Office on servers. So you can open your XLSX file by using an [OpenXML API](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AD0B72FB-4A1D-4C52-BDB5-7DD7E816D046&displaylang=en) and to search it manually.

Answer (score 1):

if you use something like [aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) on your server (which we do...) you don't need to directly interact with excel (so no excel server installation is required) but it is a tad pricey.